# OpenGL on C++ problems with syntax errors

Tags: c++

the code is for a camera view to a 3D.
the code below is a header named Camera.h and when a try to compilate it the Error list returns a "syntax error: identifier 'Shader'" in the line 33

```
#include<glad/glad.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include<glm/glm.hpp>
#include<glm/packing.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include<glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>
#include<glm/vector_relational.hpp>

#include"shaderProgram.h"


class Camera
{
    public:
        glm::vec3 position;
        glm::vec3 orientation = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
        glm::vec3 up = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        int width;
        int height;

        float speed = 1.0f;
        float sensitivity = 0.5f;
         

        Camera(int width, int height, glm::vec3 pos);

        void matrix(float FOV, float nearPlane, float farPlane, Shader& shader, const char* uniform);
        void Input(GLFWwindow* window);
};
```

the .cpp is here too

```
#include "Camera.h"

Camera::Camera(int width, int height, glm::vec3 pos)
{
    Camera::width = width;
    Camera::height = height;
    position = position;
}

void Camera::matrix(float FOV, float nearPlane, float farPlane, Shader& shader, const char* uniform)
{
    glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 projection = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    view = glm::lookAt(position, position + orientation, up);
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(FOV), (float)(width / height), nearPlane, farPlane);

    int cameraViewport = glGetUniformLocation(shader.ID, uniform);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(cameraViewport, 1, GL_FALSE, value_ptr(view * projection));
}
```

i really don´t know what's wrong with the syntax. And no, i think the Input function is not important.

i try to change the '&' to a '*' but nothing happends,on the contrary, it just gave me more problems.

Comment: There is no declaration of `Shader` in the code that you are showing. So just like compiler, we can't know what it is supposed to be.

Comment: The compiler is telling that it doesn't know what `Shader` is, and it isn't defined anywhere in the code you have posted. So think about this, where do you think it is defined? Maybe in a header file somwhere? Have you included that header file in the code above?

Comment: `#include"shaderProgram.h"` Make sure that `shaderProgram.h`  does NOT include `camera.h` in any way. It must not include camera.h even via some other chain of headers.

Comment: If  `shaderProgram.h` includes `camera.h` in any way you have this question to help you break this circular dependency: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)